# type hinting so property is an array of a specific object type

Tags: php, type-hinting

I'm trying to build a configuration class called `AcmeCorpConfiguration` in PHP 7.3 which will eventually be populated using data in a JSON file.  However, a parse error is occurring on this line `public Item $itemList = [];` - it says **Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'Item' (T_STRING), expecting function (T_FUNCTION) or const (T_CONST) in C:\xampp\htdocs\PopulateObjectsFromJSONFile\version4.php on line 217**.  Here are the model classes:

```
class Item
{   
    public $itemID;
    public $description;
}

class Location
{    
    public $storeID;
    public $city;
    public $state;
}

class Fleet
{    
    public $vehicleID;
    public $type;
    public $model;
    public $year;
}

class AcmeCorpConfiguration
{
    public $company;
    public Item $itemList = [];
    public Location $locationList = [];
    public Fleet $fleetList = [];
}
```

Here are the contents of the JSON file:

```
{
    "Company":"Acme Corporation",
    "Items": [
        {"itemID":72, "description":"drill"},
        {"itemID":73, "description":"hammer"},
        {"itemID":74, "description":"pliers"}
    ],
    "Locations": [
        {"storeID":7, "city":"Omaha", "state":"NE"},
        {"storeID":9, "city":"Madison", "state":"WI"}
    ],
    "Fleet": [
        {"vehicleID":92, "type":"truck", "model":"Ford F-150", "year":2015},
        {"vehicleID":93, "type":"truck", "model":"GMC Sierra 1500", "year":2018},
        {"vehicleID":94, "type":"truck", "model":"Toyota Tundra", "year":2018},
        {"vehicleID":95, "type":"car", "model":"Toyota Lexus", "year":2019}
    ]
}
```

Why is it giving a parse error?  I have done something similar to this in C# but perhaps the type hinting syntax or general approach isn't right for PHP.

Comment: Its in the error message *Fatal error: Property of type Item may not have default value*. So try `public Item $itemList;`

Comment: Also, you need >=7.4.0alpha1 to use that feature/syntax: https://3v4l.org/5NMcp#vhhvm-3101

Comment: @LawrenceCherone It's not giving a Fatal error, rather a Parse error.  The link you provided in your second comment was quite helpful.  It looks like I'll have to wait until PHP 7.4 is available to get this to work correctly.

Comment: Yeah had to check myself, looks new to me. Though in 7.4.0 you get the error above if you do `public Item $itemList = [];`, so might need to wait for 7.5.0 for default values.